# How do I make a perfmon template?

Tags: performancecounter, perfmon

I have six machines I want to monitor with perfmon.  I want to use the same set of counters on all six.  Is there a way to set up a template so I can specify these counters one time and then base the other data collector sets off this template?  Or do I actually have to set each one up manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define Data Collector Set on one of the machines and save it as template,(XML file).

Later, on the other machines, create a 'new Data Collector Set' using the template.
First option in the wizard is "create from template"

see the guide:[Create a Data Collector Set from a Template](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766318.aspx)

Comment: My problem with this is that the template would automatically be collecting counters from the machine the template was made for.  So if I made a machine1 template and wanted to create a data collector set for machine2, it would create counters called //machine1/perfmoncounters instead of //machine2/perfmoncounters

Comment: If you Ok with running 6 perfmon instances on all machines, then you could use localhost to define counters, the template would fit each machine. If you want to collect data in one machine, you can try to edit the template:  '<Counter>\\JohnPC\ServiceModelOperation 4.0.0.0.....</Counter>'
'<Counter>\\JohnPC2\ServiceModelOperation 4.0.0.0.....</Counter>'